# How to get values from firebase with where condition

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am very new to Firebase. Why is it that I can't get what I am querying for.
In my other queries, I can actually see the payload but with this one I can't. This is the schema for my database in firebase:

[image]

I need to get the data that has the date that I need. So this is how I created my query:

```
    getSalesForToday() {
    const data = this.fireStore.collection(
      'Sales', ref => ref.where('TransactionDate', '==', formatDate(new Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'))
      );
    console.log(data);
  }
```

but it doesn't give me any result except for this:

```
AngularFirestoreCollection {ref: CollectionReference, query: Query, afs: AngularFirestore}
afs: AngularFirestore {scheduler: FirebaseZoneScheduler, firestore: Firestore, persistenceEnabled$: Observable}
query: Query {_query: Query, firestore: Firestore}
ref: CollectionReference {_query: Query, firestore: Firestore}
__proto__: Object
```

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    const data = this.fireStore.collection(
      'Sales', ref => ref.where('TransactionDate', '==', formatDate(new Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'))
      );
```

`fireStore.collection` only returns an observable. You still need to subscribe to this observable to be able to use the data.

```js
const data$ = this.fireStore.collection('Sales',
                   ref => ref.where('TransactionDate', '==', formatDate(new 
                                     Date,'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en')));

// Subscribing to collection observable to log out the data
data$.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Keep in mind you need to unsubscribe this subscription whenever it is not in use.
Also check `async pipe` for more info about the best practices of using observables in angular https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and **execute** the query:

```
getSalesForToday() {

    let query = ref.where('TransactionDate', '==', 
    formatDate(new Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'))
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
          return;
        }  

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          // Do something
          console.log(doc);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
    }
```

> ref must be the reference to the collection expected to contain the
>   value.